# Golang template ignore if no match

Tags: go, go-templates

I am trying to convert a golang template, and allow ignoring if the match is not found. Is that possible?

[Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/fMLVax-0gl)

```
package main

import (
"bytes"
"fmt"
"text/template"
)
type Person struct {
Name string
Age  int
}
type Info struct {
Name string
Id   int
}

func main() {
msg := "Hello {{ .Id }} With name {{ .Name }}"
p := Person{Name: "John", Age: 24}
i := Info{Name: "none", Id: 5}

t := template.New("My template")
t, _ = t.Parse(msg)

buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
t.Execute(buf, p)
fmt.Println(buf.String())

buf = new(bytes.Buffer)
t.Execute(buf, i)
fmt.Println(buf.String())
}
```

I would like this to print

`Hello {{ .Id }} with name John`
`Hello 5 With name none`

Comment: I don't think so. Why would you need that ?

Comment: I have a single template that I like to pass it through array of structs to get the final value. So I need the `Execute` function to just ignore if the value is not found.

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to print name only when it's not an empty string:

```
"Hello {{ .Id }} With name {{ if .Name }}{{ .Name }}{{ end }}"
```

Else, if you want to it print something else:

```
"Hello {{ .Id }} With name {{ if .Name }}{{ .Name }}{{ else }}none!{{ end }}"
```

[Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/kopCLS6Zx1) - also see [the comparison operators](http://golang.org/doc/go1.2#text_template) for html/template and text/template.

Answer (score 0):

A template can contain if statements which allow you to do what you would need.  The following example allows displaying a list if supplied, or when not supplied putting a message.

```
    {{if .MyList}}
      {{range .MyList}}
        {{.}}
      {{end}}
    {{else}}
      There is no list provided.
    {{end}}
```

Using this approach I think you can achieve what you need. But it might not be pretty as you want to leave the unprocessed `{{.Id}}` in place.